# Select fields from table which weren't added for the last four weeks

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Id [int]
UserId [int]
ProductId [int]
Created [datetime]
```

Every user can select any product at any time. No restrictions. For a report I have to select all products which haven't been chosen for four weeks.

I tried the following approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId FROM table WHERE Created > 'Three weeks ago' AND Created < 'today'
```

Problem: This result also gives Ids for products which were added today if they were also added three weeks ago.

For example, if I have the following data:

```
Id    UserId    ProductId    Created
1     1         3            2014-09-26
2     2         1            2014-08-12
3     3         3            2014-07-26
4     1         2            2014-06-26
5     6         4            2014-05-26
```

I want the query to return the ProductIds 1, 2 and 4 NOT 3, since it has been chosen by a user during the last four weeks.

I'm a little stuck. Does anyone know a way to achieve what I'm looking for via MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple GROUP BY query, you can select distinct products their respective last `Created` dates:

```
SELECT
  ProductId,
  MAX(Created) AS LastCreated
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  ProductId
;
```

Now, this would just return all the products without filtering but you need to filter on `LastCreated`. Since that column is aggregated, you can filter on it using a HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT
  ProductId
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  ProductId
HAVING
  MAX(Created) < 'Three weeks ago'
;
```

The actual `'Three weeks ago'` expression would depend on the flavour of SQL your product is using. In SQL Server, for instance, the condition would look like this:

```
  MAX(Created) < DATEADD(WEEK, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use MSSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId
  FROM table
 WHERE Created BETWEEN dateadd(week,-3,getdate()) and dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) ;
```

**Edit:** Exclude today

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm afraid I made myself not quite clear in the question. I only want to retrieve ProductIds which haven't been used by anyone during the last four weeks. Your query just returns rows which have been added during the last four weeks.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM Table
WHERE Created Between date()-1 and date()-21
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm afraid I made myself not quite clear in the question. I only want to retrieve ProductIds which haven't been used by anyone during the last four weeks. Your query just returns rows which have been added during the last four weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue using a nested SELECT statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId 
FROM table
WHERE ProductId  NOT IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ProductId
  FROM table WHERE Created > dateadd(week,-4,getdate())
)
```

This selects all the ProductIds which have been added during the last four weeks and than selects all other ProductIds from the whole table.

Thanks to @rob and @Edi G. for pointing me in the right direction!